# jwplayer video not working in IE9 normal mode

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jwplayer

I'm having a problem with JW Player which not working in IE9 normal mode.
When I try to play the video in IE9 normal mode, it display an error message like this;

Error loading media: File could not be played

But its working perfectly in IE9 compatibility mode and in other browsers.

My script is like this;

```
<div id="myElement">Loading the player...</div>
<script src="/jwplayer/jwplayer.js"></script>
<script>jwplayer.key="key="</script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    jwplayer("myElement").setup({
      width: '520',
      height: '293',
      playlist: [{
        image: "/video/image.png",
        sources: [{
          file: "/video/video-640x360.m4v",
          label: "360p",
          width: '640',
          height: '360'
        },{
          file: "/video/video-1280x720.m4v",
          label: "720p",
          width: '1280',
          height: '720'
        }]
      }],
      modes: [
            {type: 'flash'},
            {type: 'html5'},
            {type: 'download'}
        ]
    });
</script>
```

Is this is problem of flash player? Any suggestions ?

Please help me, Thanks and regards,

Arun

Comment: According to [this page](http://www.longtailvideo.com/support/forums/jw-player/bug-reports/30106/jw6-file-could-not-be-played-ie9/), that could be caused by video files not being served with the correct mime-type.

Comment: Can you please explain this little bit more?

Comment: The web server which sends back the video files to jwplayer will need to make sure that the `Content-Type` header for the video is correct (for `.m4v` files, I believe it should be `video/x-m4v`). You can use most browsers' developer tools to check if this is the case (or use an online service like [this](http://planetsvg.com/tools/mime.php)).

Comment: Do you have a link to where you are running this code?